# Plot all data within a rectangle

Tags: r, plot, frequency

I want to plot everything within a rectangle. I want the rectangle to be the total length of X as a percent (so 100%). I want to shade in the rectangle with the percentage of the occurrence of the value on the the y axis of this plot. I have attached a histogram and plot that has the data I am looking for. I just want to make this into a shade rectangle. Is this possible?

```
x <- sample(10:20, 44, TRUE)
h = hist(x)
h$density = h$counts/sum(h$counts)*100
plot(h,freq=F)
```

Comment: You can avoid a lot of this code. Just use `hist(x, freq = F, col = "skyblue")`.

Comment: Thanks Jason, It has been noted!

Comment: also Jason this gives me not a percent of each value / the sum of the values

Comment: Sure it does, it just doesn't multiply by 100 and add a percent sign.

Comment: Gregor, you are correct! I am sorry Jason. I am having major brain farts today.